# Add the label for the value to display above the bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I created a bar chart and would like to place the count value above each bar.

```
# Import the libraries
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city_code':[1200013, 1200104, 1200138, 1200179, 1200203],
    'index':['good', 'bad', 'good', 'good', 'bad']
})

# Plot the graph
df['index'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='darkcyan',
                                            figsize=[15,10])
plt.xticks(rotation=0, horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("cities", fontsize=16)
```

I'm getting the following result

[image: Graph]

I would like to add the values ​​at the top of each bar. The values ​​of the count I got from value_counts.
Something like this:

[image: Graph I want]

Thanks to everyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using `patches` and `annotate`:

```py
# Import the libraries
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "city_code": [1200013, 1200104, 1200138, 1200179, 1200203],
        "index": ["good", "bad", "good", "good", "bad"],
    }
)

# Plot the graph
ax = df["index"].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", color="darkcyan", figsize=[15, 10])
plt.xticks(rotation=0, horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("cities", fontsize=16)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(
        str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x() + 0.25, p.get_height() + 0.1), fontsize=20
    )
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ax.text` to add the label one by one, use a for loop.

But there is already a built in [method](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label) in matplotlib to do this.

You can change the line `df['index'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='darkcyan', figsize=[15,10])` in your example into

```
d = df['index'].value_counts()
p = ax.bar(d.index, d.values,color='darkcyan')
ax.bar_label(p)
```

The complete example will be:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city_code':[1200013, 1200104, 1200138, 1200179, 1200203],
    'index':['good', 'bad', 'good', 'good', 'bad']
})

# Plot the graph
d = df['index'].value_counts()
p = ax.bar(d.index, d.values,color='darkcyan')
ax.bar_label(p)
plt.xticks(rotation=0, horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("cities", fontsize=16)
fig.show()
```

And the output image looks like this:

[image]